# Returning a default response for items not found at the given xpath using itemloader in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to return default value when no value is returned by the specified xpath in itemloader. Here is a bit of my spider. Am using very basic version of the itemloader :

```
il = ItemLoader(item = HomesItem(), response=response)
il.add_xpath('Company_Name', u'//*[@id="anchor_realtorOutline"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "会社名")]/following-sibling::td/p[1]/ruby/text()')
```

So if this xpath does not return a value then i want to store `N/A` in place of it.
Somewhat like we do here:
`.extract_first(default="N/A")` 
and i need to use itemloader to concatenate a few xpaths for the same field.
Sorry if this is silly , am not very good at scrapy yet.
Thanks.

Comment: Wow...no one wants to answer ? Or the question is stupid itself.

Comment: _"Wow...no one wants to answer ?"_: maybe no one knows how to answer, maybe there's no answer. Do not expect the community to jump in at every question and provide an answer within a few days. Personally, I don't know of anything built-in in scrapy for this. You can probably build a item pipeline to add default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add xpath, then check is the field set or not, and then add default value in case field is empty. Like here:

```
il = ItemLoader(item = HomesItem(), response=response)
il.add_xpath('Company_Name', u'...')
if not il.get_output_value('Company_Name'):
    il.add_value('Company_Name', 'N/A')
```